# How to obtain type reference parameterized by the input class arg?

Tags: java, generics

Is there any way to solve the following problem by using parameterized type? I have a parameterized class object and I want to obtain another class object parameterized with the same type. It's easier to check code than explain in words:

```java
public class GenericsCheck {

    static class Fruit {}
    static class Apple extends Fruit {}
    static class Banana extends Fruit {}

    static class FruitBox<T extends Fruit> {}
    static class AppleBox extends FruitBox<Apple> {}
    static class BananaBox extends FruitBox<Banana> {}

    static class Puzzle<T extends Fruit> {

        public Class<FruitBox<T>> getBoxByFruitType(Class<T> fruitType) {
            // COMPILER ERROR
            // Required type: Class<FruitBox<T>>
            // Provided: Class<AppleBox>
            if (fruitType == Apple.class) return AppleBox.class;
            if (fruitType == Banana.class) return BananaBox.class;
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("I don't know");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Puzzle().getBoxByFruitType(Apple.class));
    }
}
```

I know that generics are invariant. The question is: are there any workarounds? Maybe something that includes some kind of type reference wrapper...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
public class GenericsCheck {

static class Fruit {}
static class Apple extends Fruit {}
static class Banana extends Fruit {}

static class FruitBox<T extends Fruit> {}
static class AppleBox extends FruitBox<Apple> {}
static class BananaBox extends FruitBox<Banana> {}

static class Puzzle<T extends Fruit,D extends FruitBox<T>> {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public  Class<D> getBoxByFruitType(Class<T> fruitType) {
        if (fruitType == Apple.class) 
            return (Class<D>) AppleBox.class;
        if (fruitType == Banana.class) 
            return  (Class<D>) BananaBox.class;
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("I don't know");
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new Puzzle().getBoxByFruitType(Apple.class));
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [*wildcards*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html):

```
static class Puzzle<T extends Fruit> {
    public Class<? extends FruitBox<? extends Fruit>> getBoxByFruitType(Class<T> fruitType) {
        if (fruitType == Apple.class) return AppleBox.class;
        if (fruitType == Banana.class) return BananaBox.class;
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("I don't know");
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, I know about wildcards. But no, it doesn't solve the puzzle. Your method returns `FruitBox`, but compiler doesn't know what exactly type of `Fruit` it contains. Method return type can't be changed, because API that uses `Puzzle` class have to know the type of fruit box contains.

Comment: @Evan “but compiler doesn't know what exactly type of `Fruit` it contains” — It *can’t* know this. There is nothing in the type system which establishes that a `FruitBox<T>` always corresponds to a `Fruit<T>`. You *assume* this, but nothing in the type system guarantees that this is true, and you *can’t* give this guarantee. Furthermore, `Class<AppleBox>` is not a `Class<FruitBox<Apple>>`. It’s a `Class<? extends FruitBox<Apple>>`, but that’s different.

Comment: Yes, that why I've said "workaround". There're situations where you just can't play fair with generics, because of their limitations, type erasure and stuff. I've asked exactly about that situation.

Comment: @Evan Sure, then go with the other solution but be aware that you’ve *also* changed the return type there, and the `D` is essentially equivalent to a named generic wildcard. In fact, since you said you can’t change the return type I’m puzzled that the other solution works for you. *If* it does, you could achieve the same with wildcards, without needing to introduce an (unused) name for the generic.

Comment: Actually there’s a *slight* difference that I currently don’t really understand — the other solution allows assigning the result to an object of type `Class<AppleBox>` without a cast, whereas my solution requires that cast at the call site. Not really sure why, since `D` isn’t `AppleBox`, it’s `extends FruitBox<Apple>`. From my understanding this should still require a cast, since I could just define another `class SnappleBox extends FruitBox<Apple> {}`. Java sliently accepts this, and doesn’t even raise an exception, it just *stores the wrong type*! WTF.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: "Actually there’s a slight difference that I currently don’t really understand" The code is using a raw type (`Puzzle` is a parameterized class, but you guys are doing `new Puzzle()`), and generics is turned off in expressions using a raw type, so it's as if `getBoxByFruitType()` returns type `Class` instead of `Class<D>`. And a raw type can be implicitly assigned to a parameterized type (with a warning).

Comment: @KonradRudolph: If they had instead used your code but with a generic method (e.g. `public <D extends FruitBox<T>> Class<D> getBoxByFruitType(Class<T> fruitType)`), and then without a raw type (e.g. `new Puzzle<Apple>().getBoxByFruitType(Apple.class)`, it would still be true that it can be assigned to a variable of type `Class<AppleBox>`, because a generic method is supposed to mean that the code is valid no matter what the type argument is (or, equivalently, the type argument can be chosen arbitrarily by the caller). Of course, it's not safe in this case but the compiler did warn about it.

Comment: @newacct Ah of course, duh. I simply overlooked that.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most correct way to implement this is something like this:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class GenericsCheck {

    static class Fruit {}
    static class Apple extends Fruit {}
    static class Banana extends Fruit {}

    static class FruitBox<T extends Fruit> {}
    static class AppleBox extends FruitBox<Apple> {}
    static class BananaBox extends FruitBox<Banana> {}

    static class Puzzle {

        private Map<Class<? extends Fruit>,
                    Class<? extends FruitBox<? extends Fruit>>> map
            = new HashMap<>();

        public Puzzle() {
            putBoxByFruitType(Apple.class, AppleBox.class);
            putBoxByFruitType(Banana.class, BananaBox.class);
        }

        public <T extends Fruit> void putBoxByFruitType(
                Class<T> fruitType, Class<? extends FruitBox<T>> boxType) {
            map.put(fruitType, boxType);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public <T extends Fruit> Class<? extends FruitBox<T>> getBoxByFruitType(
                Class<T> fruitType) {
            return (Class<? extends FruitBox<T>>) map.get(fruitType);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Puzzle().getBoxByFruitType(Apple.class));
    }
}
```

And, yes, you cannot assign the result to a variable of type `Class<AppleBox>` because that isn't safe -- as Konrad Rudolph mentioned, there can be another `class SnappleBox extends FruitBox<Apple>`, so then the method might return a `Class<SnappleBox>`.